# How to do IF/OR angular ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

If I have:

```
ng-class='{in:$first}'
```

What is the simplest way to make it add the `in` class when `$first` is true *or* if let's say the `item.in` (`$scope.item.in`) value is true ?

---

*note:* `$first` is because I have a `ng-repeat` enclosing this line but it can be any other boolean or 0/1 value if you feel the code is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `||` operator like this.

```
<div ng-class="{ in: $first || item.in }"> Test </div>
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eLPE8/**

Answer (score 1):

you can use the or operator in ng-class as such

`ng-class="{myclass: condition1 || condition2}"`

your element will gain the `myclass` class if condition1 or condition2 is true.